# 50 million records from the oracle database to vaex using from_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

The code below is from the vaex documentation:

```
pandas_df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM MYTABLE', con=engine)
df = vaex.from_pandas(pandas_df, copy_index=False)
```

**Description**

I have data more than RAM.
But, when I use above code, it try and pull all data in panda dataframe.
So to solve this I used chunksize attribute which  gives a generator.

To convert from generator to pandas dataframe again it is needs memory.
Below is the code I tried.

```
import vaex
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "user"."table"', conn, chunksize=1000000)
chunk_list = []
for i in df:
    chunk_list.append(i)
    data = pd.concat(chunk_list)
    df2 = vaex.from_pandas(data)
    alldat=df2.concat(df2)
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: This is my first post here so please ignore spelling mistakes and spacing errors. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting Memory Error?

Comment: I would pass to vaex each chunk, and export each chunk to hdf5. Then you can lazily open and concatenate all chunks, without wasting any memory.